# Restricting / monitoring wireless access in a restaurant

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm currently working for a software company that also runs a restaurant next door, and customers have recently been asking for access to the WiFi. I've been tasked with making it happen, but networking issues aren't really my thing.

The DSL hops over several routers before it gets to the wireless antenna, and signal strength is fine from the restaurant. Since our customers are generally locals and relatively "trustworthy", everyone else was okay with just supplying them our wireless password and off they go, but I'm not happy with this - firstly for security reasons, and secondly because I work off the same connection and it could slow me down considerably.

What would be the simplest way to maintain some kind of access-restriction system on the network, considering I'd like to monitor their usage, block certain ports, throttle their transfer speeds and perhaps expire passwords?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ready-made solutions. Check these links: [Sputnik](http://www.sputnik.com/), [WiFiDog](http://dev.wifidog.org/wiki/About), [ChilliSpot](http://www.chillispot.info/).